# Android RadioButtons on two lines

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-linearlayout

I want to have three radio buttons, two on one line and one on the next line.

I thought using a LinearLayout inside the RadioGroup would work for the first two and then just have the third one of the next line.

Well this doesn't work, I can just tick every radiobutton.

Anyone know a way around this or should I just do it programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadioGroup extends LinearLayout, so either you will have to rewrite RadioGroup extending relativelayout or easiest would be doing it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
your3rdRadio.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, otherRadio.getId());
```

Comment: As Nandeesh points out, RadioGroup extends LinearLayout so I don't think that will work.