# Two RadioGroups with only one selected RadioButton in each of them

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have two RadioGroups in my layout. I want that only one RadioButton should be checked at a time in RadioGroup. I've tried many methods, but none of them work properly. Now I can check every RadioButton in my RadioGroups.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

String x;
char y;

int c=1;

String num,n,type;
int d,b,o,h;
String dec,bin,hex,oct;

EditText number;
EditText result;

Button convert, clear;
RadioGroup rgFrom, rgTO;
int convertedResult;
int from=R.id.r10From;
int to=R.id.r2TO;

String stNumber; //Liczba przed przeliczeniem - string
int numbResult;  //Już int

String iterResult; //Liczba po przeliczeniu - string
int convResult;   //Już int

//int id = ((RadioGroup).findViewById( R.id.rgFrom )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();


}

 private void initialize() {
   number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
   result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResult);

    convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalculate);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReset);

    convert.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);

    rgFrom = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgFrom);
    rgTO = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTO);


    rgFrom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rgTO.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   // from = (String)findViewById(R.id.rgFrom).getSelectedItem();
   // int id = ((RadioGroup)findViewById( R.id.rgFrom )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    //from = getFrom(id);

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.r2From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r8From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r10From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r16From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case R.id.r2TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r8TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r10TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r16TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.bCalculate:
            stNumber = number.getText().toString();
            //iterResult = result.getText().toString();
            //calculate();
            break;
        case  R.id.bReset:
            //reset();
            break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rgFrom, int i) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.r2From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r8From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r10From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r16From:
            from = rgFrom.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case R.id.r2TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r8TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r10TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
        case  R.id.r16TO:
            to = rgTO.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            break;
    }
   }
}
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.converter_numeralsystem.app.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/number"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvNumber" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber"
    android:text="@string/result"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvResult" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNumber"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/enter_numb"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvNumber"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvNumber"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etResult"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/et_result"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvNumber"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvResult"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/from"
    android:id="@+id/tvFrom"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvResult"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvFrom"
    android:id="@+id/rgFrom"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/r2From"
        android:text="@string/dwa"/>


        <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/r8From"
        android:text="@string/osiem"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="75dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r10From"
            android:text="@string/dziesiec"
            android:layout_below="@id/r2From"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/r2From" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r16From"
            android:text="@string/szesnascie"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/r8From"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/r8From"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/to"
    android:id="@+id/tvTo"
    android:layout_below="@id/rgFrom"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTo"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/rgTO">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r2TO"
            android:text="@string/dwa"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r8TO"
            android:text="@string/osiem"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="75dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r10TO"
            android:text="@string/dziesiec"
            android:layout_below="@id/r2TO"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/r2TO" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r16TO"
            android:text="@string/szesnascie"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/r8TO"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/r8TO"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/rgTO">

<Button
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    android:id="@+id/bCalculate"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bReset" />

<Button
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    android:id="@+id/bReset"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bCalculate" />

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe this would help? http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: Both your RadioGroups contain a RelativeLayout (twice the same error)... why?! Remove them as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank You, it works. But how can I create something similar looking to my RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `RelativeLayout` from the `RadiGroup`. So the code would look something like:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgFrom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r2From"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="dwa" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r8From"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:text="osiem" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r10From"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="dziesiec" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r16From"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="szesnascie" />
</RadioGroup>
```

This will resolve the issue you are facing about multiple buttons being checked in same group. However, this will create a small issue in UI. I think you want 2 buttons in one line, and other two buttons in different line. As far as I know, you would have to implement your own custom layout for that. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17258573) for details. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777688), too. Hope it helps a bit.